# Autofit and vertically center text

Tags: css

I think this is a different question from other "autofit"-related questions.

I have single-line text label that I'd like to auto-fit to always be half the screen width (dynamically during and after resize, etc.) as well as centered on the page vertically and horizontally.  I've tried the [jQuery FitText plugin](http://fittextjs.com/), but it does not seem to work well with vertical centering (shifts up or down depending on the font size, sometimes below the viewport)

It may be due to my use of absolute positioning, but I can't find any alternate way to accomplish this.

My CSS:

```
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This JSFiddle shows the block I would like to fill:  http://jsfiddle.net/KFySS/6/

**Edit**: I've added a fake background image text to the fiddle above, which behaves very closely to what I'd like the real size behave to be.

I want the short text to fill the block outlined with dashed line.  It should also be centered vertically and/or horizontally.  This bounding box is just for illustration, but it was my starting point when using the Fittext plugin.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the question, do you need that oultlined block to behave like it does at the moment ? Or do you only need the text to be centered ?

Comment: As jerome.s said, the sizing of the box looks fine in the fiddle. Is it about the text that you are talking about?

Comment: have u considered using a table inside of the header?

Comment: I've updated the description and the fiddle to explain better. Yes, the text font size autofit is the important part.   The box it self is just an illustration (and was my starting point for the plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that uses the new [CSS3 vw, vh, and vmin font sizing units](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/), which sizes fonts relative to the current viewport.

```
<div>
  <h1>Hi!</h1>
</div>

div {
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 50vmin;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -25vmin;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here is an example for newer webkit browsers:

http://jsfiddle.net/uTykf/

The vertical centering approach I used seems a bit ugly, but best I could do.  Happy to hear if there's a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
h1 {
  padding: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px dashed red;
  margin: 25%;
}
```

Check out the link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/GLEcd/2/

Comment: Thanks, though I need the text resized to fill the container, not just centered.  I updated description to explain.